# Can we delete an image file using MediaStore API? if yes then how

Tags: android, file-permissions, delete-file, mediastore, android-11

I have a requirement to delete screenshot image file after a certain time using background service in my app and it was working fine using the above method

```
private void deleteTheFile(String path) {
    File fdelete = new File(path);
    if (fdelete.exists()) {
        if (fdelete.delete()) {
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));
            Log.i(TAG, "deleteTheFile: file deleted");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "deleteTheFile: file not dellleeettteeeddd");
        }
    }
```

But as everyone knows about the changes which came with android R (11)
So I tried to update my app with

> MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

But Google rejected my update saying

> Issue: Need to use Media Store API
>
> You have requested access to All Files Access permission but it
> appears that your app's core feature requires access to only Media
> Files. With the MediaStore API, apps can contribute and access media
> that's available on an external storage volume without the need for
> the access all files permission.
>
> Please update your app so that the feature uses Media Store APIs and
> remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

But I have never worked with media store API before and I don't know can it delete an image file with it, because deleting a file comes under writeable section

Answer (score 3):

Using `createDeleteRequest`

```
private fun deleteImages(uris: List<Uri>) {
  val pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, uris.filter {
    checkUriPermission(it, Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
  })
  startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.intentSender, REQ_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

using contentResolver

```
// Remove a specific media item.
val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

// URI of the image to remove.
val imageUri = "..."

// WHERE clause.
val selection = "..."
val selectionArgs = "..."

// Perform the actual removal.
val numImagesRemoved = resolver.delete(
        imageUri,
        selection,
        selectionArgs)
```

https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/main/MediaStore

This is an android official sample you can follow to have an understanding and try to implement it using MediaStoreAPI

Comment: Thank you i will try them and update the result, do I have also to use any permissions for them?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`  and 
    `<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />`

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by maxSdkVersion 28, will it not working on sdk 29 and 30?

Comment: no for deleting a file you need write access till API 28 only that is the reason to use the maxSdkVersion else on API below 29 you will get a permission issue error

Comment: so you mean if i set the max sdk 28, my app will still be able to delete files in sdk 29 and 30

Comment: @TehleelMir Is google approved after you changed to MediaStore API?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    val pendingIntent = MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(context.contentResolver, getImageDeleteUri(context, filePath))
    context.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.intentSender, requestCode, null, 0, 0, 0)}

//finally handle it's result in onActivityResult
```

getting delete uri from image path:

```
fun getImageDeleteUri(context: Context, path: String): Uri? {
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
      arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID),
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?",
      arrayOf(path),
      null
    )
    val uri = if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID))
    ) else null
    cursor?.close()
    return uri
```

}